# HTML container exceeds window height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, exceed

I am using kendo ui and boostrap v3.

[image]

I have a container for my top menu and a container for my main content (**id=splitter**).

Window height equals **981px**, but instead of dividing up the height for both containers, the main content reserves **981px** and the top menu **53px**, which sums up to **1014px**.

But there should be the following allocation -> **53px** for top menu and **928px** for the main content. I do not know how to do that.

I already tried to calculate the height with **"calc(100% - 53px)"**, but that doesn't work.

This is my html structure:

```
<div id="wms-app" style="height: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 100%;">
        <div id="wms-content" style="height: 100%;">
            <div id="mainmenu" class="k-content"></div>
            <div id="splitter" class="k-content" style="height: 100%;"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution:**

In the end it also worked with the calc(..) option:

```
#splitter {style="height: calc(100% - 53px);"}
```

I forgot to reload everything because kendo framework recalculates the splitter heights after page has been loaded.

Comment: can you add a link to your page so I can inspect css or provide me with css styles for wms-app, wms-content, mainmenu, k-content and splitter?

Comment: Sorry to be contradictory, but just to counter OhHendrie; usually, posting directl inks to one's site isn't really preferred for Stack Overflow questions. If the site goes down a year from now, some kendo debugger will get no use out of a Google search that takes them to this page. If you can reproduce the issue in a small in-question sample, go for that, otherwise just post as much code as you feel could be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might already know:

100% height sets an element to take up every available pixel of height, so the behaviour is correct.

Depending on what end result and method you favor, I see three solutions:

One solution is to set the topmenu to

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
```

That should make the menu flow above the 100% content. You will then need to position content inside the `div` in a way that accounts for the menu.

Second solution is to set the topmenu to `position:absolute`, which should also take it out of the flow, but stay in place when you scroll.

A third solution is something like this, which should work but that I haven't tested for myself.

```
#topmenu
{
    height: 53px;
}
div
{
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -53px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'd like to do is along the lines of this concept (correct me if I'm wrong).

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Hope this helps!